# Getting a warning in console "You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before."."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to implement a Redux in a simple React application that uses the latest version (React 18).  Here is my code in `index.js` so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { store, App } from './App';
import { createStore } from 'redux'

export const renderApp = () => {
    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />);
}

renderApp()

store.subscribe(renderApp)
```

However, I get a warning in the console that says:

> "You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has
> already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call
> root.render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it"

What is the supposed to mean, and how would I need to change my code in index.js?

Comment: you're calling `renderApp` and also passing it to `subscribe` which will call it again. The error is very descriptive, only createRoot once and then reuse the returned root. You should instead be passing a callback to subscribe which uses the already created root.

Comment: Simply remove `renderApp()` from your code. You're calling it manually, and then the subscriber is also doing it.

Comment: @code the subscription will call the passed callback repeatedly, so the callback should be using an already initialized root.

Comment: @code- if I remove the renderApp() line then my component doesn't even render in the first place

Comment: See also [React-18 | You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71792005/react-18-you-are-calling-reactdomclient-createroot-on-a-container-that-has-a/75052925#75052925)

Answer (score 1):

The most basic implementation would be something like the following, which creates a single root, renders against it, and then passes a callback which closes over that root for further subscription calls.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);

store.subscribe(() => root.render(<App />));
```